# nginx: proxy tcp traffic depending on remote ip

Tags: nginx

I want to use nginx to proxy tcp traffic to different backends depending on the ip address of the requester. So far I have the following setup in nginx.conf:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen 1025;
        if ($remote_addr != 10.0.99.18) {
            proxy_pass mailcatcher_production:1025;
        }
        if ($remote_addr = 10.0.99.18) {
            proxy_pass mailcatcher_others:1025;
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following error when starting nginx:

`[emerg] 1#1: "if" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:36`

I think, it's not important, but I'm running nginx in docker and copy the nginx.conf at startup time into the container.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the map module :

```
stream {
    map $remote_addr $mailcatcher {
        10.0.99.18 mailcatcher_others;
        default mailcatcher_production;
    }

    server {
        listen 1025;
        proxy_pass $mailcatcher:1025;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this and got an exception `javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 1025, response: -1`